# Filter grouped LongList items according to given text

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I've implemented my grouped LongList example using this guide: http://www.csharpteacher.com/2014/02/a-z-grouped-list-in-longlistselector.html

My ItemsSource assignment:

```
var groupedCompaniesList =
                from list in Companies
                group list by list.category into listByGroup
                select new KeyedList<string, Company>(listByGroup);

MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = new List<KeyedList<string, Company>>(groupedCompaniesList);
```

I try to add a search functionality in this list but I can't find a way to make it work. For example, I tried adding this in the above code:

```
where list.company.StartsWith(searchbox.Text.ToLower())
```

Didn't work out.

Any suggestions?